# how to use react-watermark-component library inside the code to get the watermark over an image- ReactJs

Tags: reactjs

I want to add a watermark over an image file. I'm using the "https://libraries.io/npm/react-watermark-component" npm library to achieve the result. so far I have:

```
  render() {
  const waterMarkOptions = {
      chunkWidth: 200,
      chunkHeight: 60,
      textAlign: "left",
      textBaseline: "bottom",
      globalAlpha: 0.17,
      font: "14px Microsoft Yahei",
      rotateAngle: -0.26,
      fillStyle: "#666"
    };
    <ReactWaterMark
            waterMarkText="Confidenatiality"
            openSecurityDefense
            options={waterMarkOptions}>
      <MyComponent>
      .
      .
      .
    </MyComponent>
    </ReactWaterMark>
}
```

But doing this it does nothing, it does not add any watermark to the component.

I also tried the watermar.js - https://github.com/brianium/watermarkjs
but I'm sure of its usage inside a ReactComponent.

This is the usage:

```
const options = {
  init(img) {
    img.crossOrigin = 'anonymous'
  }
};
watermark(['http://host.com/photo.jpg', 'http://host.com/logo.png'], options)
  .image(watermark.image.lowerRight(0.5))
  .then(img => document.getElementById('container').appendChild(img));
```

Mycomponent:

```
export default class Dialog extends React.Component {
  render() {
     return <div>
  //where should I insert the watermark script?
</div>
}
}
```

Just FYI, my component is a dialog box and I have text/images inside.
Note: For testing purpose I have added water mark to the entire component, however I;d want to add water precisely on the image. But before that I want to see if I''m making use of  component correctly.
any idea?

Comment: Do you mind adding into code sandbox with Dialog box the way you are using seems good to me. I found this one if it helps you https://codepen.io/liyan/pen/LMWGKJ else please put your code in sandbox and I will take a lookt

Comment: @Garry, thanks for you help, this is my Dialog component -https://codesandbox.io/s/react-example-z67s0 and I'm using <ReactWaterMark/> on this component the way I mentioned above. Please lmk if you need more details

Comment: Here you can find working code https://codesandbox.io/embed/react-example-f8eep. Let me know if you would need more help.

Comment: Thanks @Garry, this helped

Comment: your welcome @user1234